# Can I do anything to make this look better?

Tags: repair

Would caulk hide chips in veneer from an MDF panel?

[image]
<sup>Click for full size</sup>

It's a fitted wardrobe with a plastic covering which had been chipped during the cutting process.

From what I have read, this is inevitable so looking for options to try and make the unit look more neat as it looks pretty rough at the moment.

The units are a light grey matt finish.

Comment: Paint the chipped areas carefully with a matching coloured paint

Comment: Hard to tell whats going on in that picture, but can you caulk that gap with the chipping?

Comment: It's not inevitable if you use the right blade and cut from the other side.

Comment: Please take the [tour]. You've more or less duplicated your [earlier question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/248711/chipped-veneer-on-fitted-wardrobes#comment491364_248711) where you probably should've updated and improved it.

Comment: And as with the earlier question I can't tell what I'm looking at. Is some of that the wall? Please give us more context and scale.

Comment: Define "looks better". Define "Can I". Don't know if you've got the skills or not. "Looks" is an arts & crafts question and is off-topic. "Better" is opinion based and is off-topic.

Comment: That was installed by someone who didn't know you saw from the face with a hand saw, but from the reverse with a jig-saw. That's a newbie error. Caulk is about your only option… note it will yellow over time unless you use [shiny] silicone rather than caulk, so this will never actually go away, just need re-doing every 5 years.

Answer (score 2):

Try grey silicone sealer, but before you apply, put a line of masking tape as close to the edge as you feel necessary, so that when the silicone has gone off, there's a nice line down the panel.